# External Monitor is not Working with Windows 8.1 64bit (MacBook Pro Late 2011)

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, displayport, windows, dvi

I need to connect my Macbook Pro Late 2011 to external (LG) monitor via Minidisplay port to DVI. I have the latest drivers for my Intel HD Graphics 3000 and the latest Bootcamp as well.

Can anybody help? I went through a lot of forums, but nothing helped me.

Answer (score 1):

Are you dual-booting or using a VM? Unless you have a specific reason for it like critical h/w performance or driver incompatibility, I always prefer using a VM for ease of use. And in this case the Windows video driver would be auto installed.

Comment: I am using dual-booting (VM worked fine, but I don't use it anymore).